# CSS Opacity Transitions glitch on iPad Pro Retina

Tags: ipad, css-transitions, opacity

I'm having trouble on iPad Pro Retina with basic css opacity transitions

```
.fading-element {
    transition: opacity 1s;
    opacity: 1;
}

.fading-element.fade {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

This works fine everywhere else but on iPad Pro on both Safari/Chrome the completed state appears momentarily before the transition begins.

https://codepen.io/mradammorley/pen/vWPxQG

Comment: This appears to be an issue with iOS 11.1.2

Answer (score 0):

Issue no longer on IOS 11.2, but for those not yet updated to that version, try adding -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; to affected element.

In Safari's documentation this "Overrides the highlight color shown when the user taps a link or a JavaScript clickable element in Safari on iOS."

Ref: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001266-_webkit_tap_highlight_color